# react-native scalesPageToFit don't work on version 0.30.0

Tags: webview, react-native, scale

I want to add **WebView** in my app and want to scale the page to fit into my mobile.
I use **scalesPageToFit** to do this, but it don't work in Android.
I'm using **0.30 verison** of react-native.

this is my code:

```
class Test extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {scalesPageToFit: true};
}

onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
    this.setState({
        scalesPageToFit: true
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <WebView 
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                scalesPageToFit={this.state.scalesPageToFit}
                onNavigationStateChange={() => this.onNavigationStateChange()}
                style={{height: 500}} 
                source={{uri: "http://www.avosannonces.fr"}}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

}
```

This is what I get : [This is what i get with scalesPageToFit in react-native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPE26.png)

Comment: Did you get any answer?